# Why would I be getting this uninitialized constant error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is the error I get: `uninitialized constant SellController`, when I try to go to this URL: `http://localhost:3000/port_stocks/6/sell/new`

This is my routes:

```
  resources :port_stocks do
    resources :sell
  end

  namespace :port_stocks do
    resources :buy
  end
```

This is my `app/controllers/port_stocks/sell_controller.rb`

```
class SellController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

  def create
    # Lots of code here
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_port_stock
      @port_stock = PortStock.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_portfolio
      @portfolio = current_user.portfolio
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def port_stock_params
      params.require(:port_stock).permit(:portfolio_id, :stock_id, :volume, :purchase_price, :current_price, :percent_change, :bought_on, :action)
    end
end
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are looking for a nested route, in this case your controller needs to be at

```
app/controllers/sell_controller.rb
```

not

```
app/controllers/port_stocks/sell_controller.rb
```

that type of hierarchy is for namespace, something like..

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

routes for nested will look.

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `sell` routes are trying to find the controller

```
`app/controllers/sell_controller.rb`
```

Whereas your controller is inside the `port_sockets` directory.

The nested route does not look for the nested controller. You can take a look at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

You could fire `rails routes` and see what controller your routes are sending the request to.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your routes to this:

```
namespace :port_stocks do
  resources :sell
  resources :buy
end
```